# Get lastest record from section using mvc5

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-5, linq-to-entities, asp.net-mvc-5.2

I want to show in my home page: All section (all link category and one lastest news record in this section).
Please help me to complete my code.
Thank you so much.

My DbContext class:

```
public partial class xxDbContext : DbContext
    {
        public xxDbContext()
            : base("name=xxDbConnection") { }
        public virtual DbSet<Category> Categories { get; set; }
        public virtual DbSet<Section> Sections { get; set; }
        public virtual DbSet<News> News { get; set; }
    }
    public partial class Section
    {  
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }

        public virtual List<Category> Categories { get; set; }
    }
    public partial class Category
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public int SectionId { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }

        public virtual Section Section { get; set; }
    }
    public partial class News
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public int CateId { get; set; }
        public string Title { get; set; }
        public string Content { get; set; }
    }
```

My controllers

```
public ActionResult NewsInSec()
        {
            var model = db.Sections.Where(m => m.Publish).ToList();
            return PartialView("NewsInSec", model);
        }
```

My view

```
@model IEnumerable<xx.Models.Section>
<div>
    @foreach (var sect in Model)
    {
        <ol class="breadcrumb">
            <li><a href="/Section/@sect.Id">@sect.Name</a></li>

            @foreach (var cate in sect.Categories)
            {
                <li><a href="/Cate/@cate.Id">@cate.Name</a></li>
            }
        </ol>

        **foreach (var item in sect.Categories.SelectMany(c => c.News).Where(c => c.Publish).OrderByDescending(c => c.CreateDate).Take(4).ToList())
    {
        <div>
            @* News title*@
            <h4><a href="#">@item.Title</a></h4>
            <img src="~/img/news/@item.Image" />
            @*Content of lastest news*@
            <p>@item.NewsContent</p>
            <p><a href="#">@item.Title</a></p>
        </div>
    }**
    }
```

Finally, i want to show section, cate, news as my attached photo.
[image]
Please help me to see and fix my code above one more time? Thanks and thanks so much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add navigation property in Category for easy access to News.

```
public partial class Category
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int SectionId { get; set; }
    ...

    public virtual List<News> News { get; set; }    
}
```

And select last news for section:

```
@foreach (var cate in sect.SelectMany(s=>s.Categories.SelectMany(c=>c.News))
.OrderByDescending(n=>n.ID).Take(5))
 {
  <div>
            // Title of lastest news
            <h3></h3>
            <img src="~/img/...." />
            // Content of lastest news
            <p></p>
        </div>
}
```

Note: more correct way find last news in your Controller and include result in ViewModel, Like that:

```
public class SomeViewModel
{
  public IEnumerable<Section> Sections {get;set;}
  public IEnumerable<News> LastNews{get;set;}
}
```

Fill this model in controller and pass in view.

Comment: There was error in my view: 'xx.Models.Section' does not contain a definition for 'SelectAll' and no extension method 'Select All' accepting a first argument of type 'xx.Models.Section' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?

Comment: @giathienphu Sorry, change SelectAll to SelectMany

Comment: Now everything is ok and select last news for section is foreach (var cate in sect.Categories.SelectMany(c => c.News).OrderByDescending(c => c.ID).Take(4){ ....}. Thanks you so much @awesome